# Problems installing CPAN Modules

Tags: windows, perl, module, cpan

i'm having loads of problem in trying to install CPAN Modules. Using the cpan.exe, I try to install a module with, for example, "install Win32::IE::Mecahnize" but I end up hitting a wall. In the beginning it find dmake.EXE and is okay, but when the install finishes it says dmake.exe is NOT OK, and Dmake.exe Error code 255 , while making 'test-dynamic'.

I'm very confused as to what is happening and why its not working?? Help is much appreciated.

This is the current error I get:
`dmake.EXE: Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE test -- NOT OK

Running make install

  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force

ABELTJE/Win32-IE-Mechanize-0.009.tar.gz     : make_text NO`

Comment: ya, well here's the thing, I have both ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl installed, is that a problem?

Comment: Is there any message between where things are "ok", and there it finishes with "not ok"?  Usually there would be a slew of other messages along the way, and generally the messages higher up on the list indicating failure are the first place to check.

Answer (score 6):

It's not your fault. That module doesn't work for anyone. When you run into a failure with a module, investigate it to see if other people are having problems. You can look on [its CPAN Search page](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Win32-IE-Mechanize-0.009/) to see that there are no passing [testers reports for that distribution](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/Win32-IE-Mechanize.html#Win32-IE-Mechanize-0.009). That distribution should not install without force. We cover some of this in [Effective Perl Programming](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com)'s section on researching modules.

Can you install other modules without a problem?

Comment: hey @brian I landed here because my CPAN testers report says my first [CPAN Module](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Github)  failed with this same error on WinXP machines. Could you please give me any clues as to why this happens?

Comment: I'm the wrong guy to ask about Windows. Maybe you can ask on some forum website that answers programming questions. :)

Comment: ah! thanks for your reply. yea I figured finally that it's the pod coverage tests failing because I haven't documented a private function.(Didn't really want to document it) but `podcoverage.t` fails on windows machines. Anyhoo..will get to the bottom of it soon! :)

Answer (score 1):

> ya, well here's the thing, I have both ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl installed, is that a problem?

Shouldn't be an issue. However, you need to make sure that Strawberry Perl's distro contains the binaries and libraries you need to build and install non-text only modules. You need to make sure you're using Strawberry Perl's stuff and not ActivePerl. I recommend putting Strawberry Perl in your PATH, but not ActivePerl.

Easiest thing to do is not use CPAN, but ActivePerl's own [PPM](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html) manager. ActivePerl has probably prebuilt about 90% of the CPAN modules and have them available via their *PPM* manager. Try that.

Comment: I changed the Path to just Strawberry Perl, but still no

Comment: ya couldn't find this one, its relatively new

Comment: I failed to find a way to install ppm. The doc said *PPM is installed automatically with ActivePerl.* But I have installed ActivePerl's perl. And there is no ppm executable inside perl's installation directory.