# CPAN dmake.exe: Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'

Tags: perl, cpan, dmake

I start using Strawberry Perl and wanted to install some modules using the cpan command. But i receive the error message "Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'".

First i tried to install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox finding that i miss three other module: MozRepl::RemoteObject 0.39; Object::Import and Shell::Command. The first two of those 3 give the same error message. The Shell::Command installed whitout any error message.

MozRepl::RemoteObject 0.39:

```
 Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 3 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2-3
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/16-plugin-repl-home.t             (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t (Wstat: 768 Tests: 4 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  2-4
  Non-zero exit status: 3
t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t     (Wstat: 768 Tests: 7 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  2-3, 5
  Non-zero exit status: 3
t/20-plugin-json.t                  (Wstat: 256 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=14, Tests=58,  6 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.06 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 5/14 test programs. 10/58 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
Stopping: 'test' failed for 'MozRepl'.
```

Object::Import

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_handle.t  (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 56 tests but ran 3.
Files=14, Tests=265,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.16 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/14 test programs. 0/265 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Object::Import'.
Failed during this command:
 AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz            : make_test NO
```

I'm not a Perl programmer, just startet.

/edit: the other question is about another package. I read the cpantesters page and the packages should be OK. But could it be that there is something whit the 64-bit version. On the cpantesters site are all windows related entries are for win32:

http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/O/Object-Import.html#Object-Import-1.004
http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/MozRepl-RemoteObject.html#MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.39

/edit2: Tried to get some reports and run both installs again, now it looks like the MozRepl::RemoteObject went good, but the Object::Import didn't: So here is the error report from that:

```
Running install for module 'Object::Import'
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\A\AM\AMBRUS\Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Object::Import
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
cp lib/Object/Import.pm blib\lib\Object\Import.pm
  AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00_require.t ... ok
t/01_basic.t ..... ok
t/02_auto.t ...... ok
t/03_bigint.t .... ok
t/04_handle.t .... 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 53/56 subtests 
t/05_nometh.t .... ok
t/06_deref.t ..... ok
t/07_mary.t ...... ok
t/08_target.t .... ok
t/09_parm.t ...... ok
t/10_alias.t ..... ok
t/11_exporter.t .. ok
t/12_taint.t ..... ok
t/13_meta.t ...... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_handle.t  (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 56 tests but ran 3.
Files=14, Tests=265,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.16 CPU)
Result: FAIL
  AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.004.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Object::Import'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems installing CPAN Modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600793/problems-installing-cpan-modules)

Comment: As i told in the http://stackoverflow.com/a/42833906/632407 - me never used windows. The answer works in my Mac, but i haven't idea how to cope with the installation problems in windows... so sry...

Comment: Please show the output for the tests that failed. It will be higher up in the build log. The test summary is not detailed enough.

Comment: Just posted the outcome. Now the MozRepl did not gave this error message, and i believe the other one is different now.